# How many outcomes for 16 light switches

Tags: probability

So my schools asking, what is the outcome for 16 switches, but they gave us counters, and that'll take a long time. So I'm trying to find a formula to calculate it easier. I saw on a different website that it could be (x . y)^n (x times y to the power of n) but I don't know where to put everything, and I don't know if that formula will even work. I don't know where to find y or n.

Comment: Try solving smaller instances of the problem (what is the answer if there is only one light switch? what about 2 switches? 3 switches?) and see if you can find a pattern. In doing so you will discover the "formula" for yourself.

Comment: See [The Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product#:~:text=In%20combinatorics%2C%20the%20rule%20of,ways%20of%20performing%20both%20actions.).  Here... we have 2 choices for the state of the first switch (*presumably*)... 2 choices for the second... 2 choices for the third... etc.  Take the product of the number of options for each step.

Comment: It is worth clarifying however what types of switches these are.  [DIP switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIP_switch) often have binary states for each switch (*either on or off*), but there do also exist tri-state switches (*+, 0, -*)

Comment: What do you mean by 'outcome;?

Comment: by outcome I mean that since there are 2 options, on and off, and we're applying that to 16 light switches, how many outcomes are there, and what's the formula to get the answer. is it 2 to the power of 16? (2 to the power of amount of switches)

Comment: Yes, it's $2^{16}$. You can think of each switch as bit and find what is the maximum number that fits into 16 bits then add 1 to that number to account for zero.